# Interaction term between a continous and ordinal variable in a multilevel regression

Tags: interaction, multilevel-analysis

I want to compute an interaction term between the variable individual income (1-level) and the gini coefficient (2 level) in a multilevel model. Unfortunately, the income variable is categorical containing 10 categories. How can I hanlde this? 
I am not sure if the number of groups matters when computing a cross level interaction, but in my case I only have 21 groups(countries).

Comment: You have 21 observations, and a categorical variable with 10 levels. Is that correct?

Comment: @Dex Groves probably there are more observations, I assume there are around 20000-25000 individuals clustered in countries. Could you provide more information about the data, dependent and independent variables? Are the categories of income variable intervals (10000-15000, 50000+, etc)?

Comment: I have around 80 000 individuals clustered into 21 countries over 4 waves. The income variable has 10 categories. Depending on the country people could choose either from a weekly or a montly income category:

Comment: Weekly income: 1 category: less than 40 Euros; 2 category: 40 to under 70; 3 category: 70 to under 120; 4. cat: 120 to under 230; 5 cat: 230 to under 350; 6. cat: 350 to under 460; 7 cat: 460 to under 580; 8 cat: 580 to under 690; 9 cat 690 to under 1150; 10 cat 1150 to under 1730